# Batch Script Move file to directory based on its current directory

Tags: batch-file

I'm attempting to sort a lot of files based on the current location of the file e.g.:

```
File 1 is located at C:\Work\Movies\Subs\Subtitle.txt
File 2 is located at C:\Work\Movies\Subs\Special\Subtitle.txt
File 3 is located at C:\Work\MoviesSpanish\Subs\Subtitle.txt
```

I'm trying to move the files like so:

```
File 1 to C:\Work\InProgress\Movies\Subs\Subtitle.txt
File 2 to C:\Work\InProgress\Movies\Subs\Special\Subtitle.txt
File 3 to C:\Work\InProgress\MoviesSpanish\Subs\Subtitle.txt
```

The Batch Script is to be located in `C:\Work\MoveFile.bat`

There are away more files then I listed above. Just for an estimate I would say around 300-500 per folder and there's a lot more subdirectories (e.g. `.\Subs\01\` all the way up to `.\Subs\300\` and they each contain a bunch of text files). I need to move all of the .txt files from their current locations to a new folder in `C:\Work\` while retaining the rest of the directory location. So they get moved to `C:\Work\[New Folder]\[Rest of Original Location]`

I want to do this in batch but I'm not sure where to start. I already have the following code, which deletes files that don't contain a specific string:

```
for /r %%Z in (*.txt) do (
    SET "count="
    for /F "usebackq delims=," %%A in ("%%Z") do (
        if /i "%%A"=="LN" set count=1
    )
    if not defined count echo del "%%Z"
    if not defined count del "%%Z"
    if defined count move "%%Z"
    echo %count%
    echo %%Z
)
```

But I'm not sure how to obtain the correct directory to move them into. I was thinking about `for` loop that reads the directory string of the file in question and uses `delims=/` but it kept reading the text file rather then the path (and when I didn't use quotes on %%Z, it decided it couldn't find the file).

Comment: Use `xcopy` to copy directory structure with `rd` to delete it after copying or use `robocopy`. You get help on those commands on running them in a command prompt window with `/?` as parameter.

Comment: But Im still not sure what to set as the [destination]... trying to figure that out... Since If I copy the directory structure wont it essentially be doing nothing? Or do I need to make the Running directory the new folder?

Comment: Did you only want `*.txt` files processed?

Comment: Yes I only want *.txt files to be moved

Comment: I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested - it uses `robocopy` to move the `*.txt` files into a new location which is outside the source folder (because of cyclic copy restrictions) and then moves them back to the new `"C:\Work\InProgress"` folder.

If `%temp%` and `c:\work` are on the same drive then it should be swift.

Change `c:\work` in both places to a test folder with a few `copies` of your files and test it.

```
@echo off
robocopy "C:\Work" "%temp%\temporarymoviefolder"            *.txt /s /mov
robocopy "%temp%\temporarymoviefolder" "C:\Work\InProgress" *.txt /s /mov
pause
```

Comment: Thanks Il give this a shot in a bit, I was unaware that robocopy could specify filetypes... my pc's bein a bit buggy right now (Lagging whenever i hit certain keys so im going to restart it and take a short break before I try the above)

Comment: @ foxidrive 
So I tested it in command line it works fine but when i run it from a bat it says invalid parameter#1 blabla, the second part works fine though. Note: I changed it to this so It would work from any location


`    @echo off
    robocopy "%~dp0" "%temp%\temporarybatchfolder" *.txt /s /mov
    robocopy "%temp%\temporarybatchfolder" "%~dp0\InProgress" *.txt /s /mov
    pause`

For some reason It wont let me set that to code.

Comment: Nevermind Figured out why it was telling me invalid parameter. "%~dp0" Needed to be "%~dp0\". Thanks for your help =)